# Is there any faster way to exit Dark souls games?

Tags: dark-souls-series

So, quitting my game then waiting to connect to the dark souls server is kinda BS. Is there a faster way to quit the game than waiting for all that?

Comment: Is this on Console or PC?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

More-or-less safe option: Force-quitting (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> for PC; <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>on Mac; or just quitting to the dashboard on console) does the job, next time you will get complain about possibility of losing progress, but after like 30 quits like this I've never lost anything. DS should save your progress each time you [interact with *anything*](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/294173/when-exactly-does-the-auto-save-save-the-game-in-dark-souls/294174#294174)).

Safer *(100% safe?)*: Alternatively, you can chose quit in the menu, then wait for "connecting to server", and only then force-quit.

Comment: On Mac, standard Quit is <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> and force quit is <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Opt</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd> .  Standard quit is definitely the safer of the two as it would at least send the appropriate termination messages to the app, whereas force quitting may very well stop the app mid-process and could possibly corrupt data.

Comment: I start to wonder why do we give an options for a Mac at all, when the game is for Windows only :D

Comment: I do this. As soon as I see that the game has returned to the "Press any key to start" screen I hit Alt+f4.

Answer (score 4):

For ds3 on PC, I've always selected quit from the start menu, waited until the game "restarts" (first publisher spash appears) then hit alt+f4. That way it saves, you don't have to wait for the main menu quit option, and it doesn't bother you about not saving.