# When exactly does the auto-save save the game in Dark Souls?

Tags: dark-souls-series

The auto-save system in Dark Souls saves quite a lot, but exactly *how often* does it save? If I was to force-quit the game, how much progress would I lose at any given time?

Comment: Funny, I was just about to ask a DS question. You can see the indicator flash quickly in the top right corner when it saves (it's very quick). I'd answer, but I don't have a specific time.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Well this kinda a "FYI" Q&A post :)

Comment: Ahh lol. Jumped the gun. Well, this is definitely good info!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The auto-save system basically removes any need for worry of losing any major progress. The game saves:

- Any time you interact with something (talk to an NPC; pick up an item; rest at/leave a bonfire; open a door/walk through a Fog Wall; etc.)
- Defeat an enemy
- Gain/Lose Souls (i.e. Die)
- Teleport
- Open the Menu/Level Up/Manage your inventory or equipment
- Quit the game
- Get queued for an invasion/summoning (the game saves *before* phantoms show up; the moment the fog gates appear, regardless of whether or not the invasion/summoning is successful), as well as when they disappear.

The *only* times that you might lose progress, is if you accidentally quit early during a boss fight. Travelling away or quitting before receiving the souls/items from a boss may require you to restart the boss fight again - even if you have seen the boss die. The other is if you are simply running from one end of the map to the other without interacting with anything. You'd simply return to the place where you left off.